# Wordpress How to retrieve results from database using $wpdb

Tags: sql, wordpress

I have a table of values and I would like a user to choose a row from the list with a drop-down menu in a WordPress page and have values from various columns populated in the same WordPress page.

I am trying to learn how to use the $wpdb class in WordPress to do this, I am trying to understand first how to write something that will be displayed in the user's browser, but I think I might be missing some critical parts:

What I have done is to create a table called 'wp_axleaa' in my WordPress database. I am trying to query this table and the only result I get printed is “Array”

I wrote a plugin as follows:

```
<?php
/**
* @package Trying to Connect
* @version 1.6
*/
/*
Plugin Name: Trying to Connect
Plugin URI:
Description: Connecting to DB with $wpdb
Author: Paul J
Version: 1.0
Author URI:
*/

function tc_info() {
    global $display;
    global $wpdb;
    $display = $wpdb->get_results(
    '
    SELECT *
        FROM $wpdb->wp_axleaa
    ');
    print $display;
    }

add_shortcode('showinfo','tc_info');
?>
```

Then I put the shortcode [showinfo] into my WordPress site, and when I view the page then it just shows “Array”. If I add a WHERE clause to the SQL statement, then I get an error message on the page.

I am very new to WordPress and writing PHP and would really appreciate any help, I'm sorry if this is a long-winded question...

Thanks very much,

Answer (score 1):

That's because get_results() returns an array. You may want to modify your code like this:

```
function tc_info() 
{
    global $wpdb;
    $output = '';

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM $wpdb->wp_axleaa';

    $rows = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );

    if ( $rows ) {
       foreach ( $rows as $row ){
     $output .= $row[0];
       }
    }
    print $output;  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not exactly retrieving the database info. **First**, Shortcode values [should be](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) *`return`ed*. Not *`print`ed* or *`echo`ed*. **Second**, you need to do something with the array you're receiving from the DB query.

To have a nicely formatted display of the array contents, instead of `print $display;`, use:

```
return '<pre>' . print_r( $display, true ) . '<pre>';
```

If you want fast progress in learning, you'll need to consult the documentation frequently:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php